# Play application with AngularJS frontend routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, playframework-2.0

Im using a the play framework to create a REST service and i want the front end written in Angularjs to make rest calls etc. I have set up a route provider like this:

```
angular.module("getAbscencePlans", ["getAbscencePlans.services"]).
config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/plans/:companyId', {templateUrl: '/assets/views/plans.html', controller: StoryListController})
        //.when('/plans/new', {templateUrl: '/assets/views/create.html', controller: StoryCreateController})
        .when('/plans/plan/:planId', {templateUrl: '/assets/views/detail.html', controller: StoryDetailController});
});
```

my index page has the correct:

```
ng-app="getAbscencePlans"
```

in the html tag at the top. However when i go to http://mywebsite.com/plans/2 for example i get a Action not found error. In my routes file i have specified a static resource for the index page, but i presumed my routeProvider would do the rest. What am i doing wrong :(

Comment: Does `/#/plans/2` work?

Comment: Did you add proper route in Play's route file to valid Play action? looks like missing one...?

Answer (score 0):

Have you generated a a JavaScript router in Play? The Play router can generate JS code to handle routing from any JS client like Angular, Knockout etc and you can then select which routes to expose for JS clients. 
To do this, follow the step-by-step instruction on Play's documentation here: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting